# Click on a hyperlink based on text which present under another tag

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have to click on a hyperlink based on some text present under `<td>`

This is the image :

[image]

And Below is Correspondent HTML :

```
<tr class="nav-table">
  <td class="selected" style="text-align:left">Production Support Hot Issues (Inc,Prb,SReq)</td>
  <td class="icon">
       <a href="?wicket:interface=:2:table:dashboardRows:3:dashboardRow:new::ILinkListener::">
          <img title="NEW" src="../resources/new.gif">
       </a>
  </td>
  <td class="icon">
       <a href="?wicket:interface=:2:table:dashboardRows:3:dashboardRow:search::ILinkListener::">
          <img title="SEARCH" src="../resources/search.gif">
       </a>
  </td>
```

I want to locate the image tag whose title is **Search**, based on `<td>` tag which having text as **Production Support Hot Issues (Inc,Prb,SReq)**.

Comment: What are your exact manual steps? Why do you want to `locate td value "Production Support Hot Issues (Inc,Prb,SReq)" and select the 2nd href tag`. Sounds like **_started for London Airport to catch a flight from NYC to Dallas_**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the xpath mentioned below:

```
//td[contains(.,'Production Support Hot Issues')]/..//img[@title='SEARCH']/..
```

Explanation:

This Xpath will first locate **td** which contains text "Production Support Hot Issues" and then will find the "img" with the title of "Search" in the same tr and will then locate the "a" tag which is the parent of "img" tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below xpath to do the same :

```
//td[contains(.,'Production Support Hot Issues (Inc,Prb,SReq)')]/following-sibling::td/a/img[@title='SEARCH']
```